# "No I2C devices found" Arduino Nano Every

Tags: arduino-nano, i2c

I was able to set up a Arduino Nano with an I2C board very easily, but the Arduino Nano Every is giving me a much harder time (my project required low profile).

Just to test, I stripped some wires, and looped them into the board, I'm not sure I want to solder on the pins as they may be too tall. Anyways, just trying to get a proof of concept going right now.

Here's how it's connected:

[image: My shitty POC]

based on this pin diagram: https://i2.wp.com/rosmianto.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Untitled-Diagram-4.png?fit=1506%2C1974&ssl=1

The screen lights up so I know the 5v and Ground connections work, but when I scan for I2C devices with i2c_scanner, it sees no devices.

```
18:20:56.254 -> Scanning...
18:20:56.289 -> No I2C devices found
18:20:56.289 -> 
18:21:01.265 -> Scanning...
18:21:01.265 -> No I2C devices found
18:21:01.300 ->
```

Comment: Looping the wires through the board and not soldering them is probably your problem.  That's not going to make a very good connection.  You may get power and ground that way, but digital signals like I2C comms are going to see a LOT of noise.

Comment: Ah, okay, I'll solder it then and see if that helps

Comment: @Delta_G Yup that was it!

Comment: stick toothpicks into the holes to tighten up the connections

Comment: @Delta_G, make that an answer so we can mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping the wires through the board and not soldering them is probably your problem. That's not going to make a very good connection. You may get power and ground that way, but digital signals like I2C comms are going to see a LOT of noise.